# Drawing tic-tac-toe boards

Tags: java, graphics

I'm making an Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe game. If you aren't familiar with the rules, that's fine. But the board layout is just a 3x3 of Tic-Tac-Toe boards. I need an algorithm, for lack of a better term, to make it so I can make `x` and `y` wherever I want and it will draw it there correctly.

```
    int width = 67; // Note: I've determined this variable means a lot to this "algorithm" because changing it changed the lines dramatically.
    g.drawRect(0, 0, x, y); // Changing this made the boxes go to the center, so this works
    g.drawLine(width, 0, width, y);
    g.drawLine(width*2, 0, width*2, y);
    g.drawLine(0, width, x, width);
    g.drawLine(0, width*2, x, width*2);
```

The Class Constructor calls for the `x` and `y` to be input, so those are varying.

Specifically, I want this to work no matter what I make the x and y coordinates be.

The last 4 lines in the code make the 4 intersection bars (shaped like a very large #).

Making 1: This works fine.

Making 2: The Horizontal(--) lines work, not the Vertical(|).

Making 3: Third box doesn't even show up.

Also note that these above 3 tests are just 1 row of Tic-Tac-Toe boards.

I also understand that `width` can not be a single value (like it is now) but changing it makes the lines go far from where they're supposed to be so I don't know what to change it to.

Comment: Perhaps try to draw this out on grid paper first and get hardcoded numbers, and than substitute letters for those numbers and then translate that into code where the letters are variables.

Comment: I think we need a lot more information before we can go about answering your question.  What are `x` and `y` in your question?  What do you mean by "wherever I want"?  What is the "it" when you say "it will draw it there correctly"?  How is your code structured, apart from the 5 methods you're calling in the code sample above?

Comment: @Dan O I specified what `x` and `y` is. It's a variable that the user enters when they create an object of the class, or in other words, it's a parameter for the class constructor. "it" is the board, and when I say "it will draw there correctly" refer to the part where I say Specifically. I also say "wherever I want" because `x` and `y` are coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not phrasing my concerns correctly.  You've provided six lines of code and a lot of phrases like "this doesn't work".  But without seeing the rest of your code, and seeing how and where and when you call that code, it's really hard to know what your specific problem is or how to fix it.

Comment: @Dan O What you see is the majority of the class though. It's a 200 by 200 JPanel and what you see is all that I do with it, other than add it to a JFrame. The reason I provided 6 lines of code is because that's where the "error" is at. It's a logic error, not a compile error. This runs fine, it just doesn't work universally (x and y being any number). I need it to work universally, and the question is how to do that.

Comment: Can you explain what `x` and `y` **mean**? Can you perhaps draw what you are supposed to get, and put the picture here, and what you are getting instead, and put that picture here, too? What do "Making 1", "Making 2" and "Making 3" mean?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I mean making 1 object, 2, and 3. I have also explained what `x` and `y` mean. They're the coordinates for the lines, mainly. It's just convenient to use them to draw the rectangle because it draws one that is the right size, making it seem like they're all separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the Java Platform documentation for the [Graphics class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html). Specifically the documentation for the [drawLine() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), and also the [drawRect() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) (although you don't strictly need drawRect() to accomplish the task).

Based on your description, it sounds like you want to reuse the four drawLine() statements from your code sample to create each of the nine small grids as well as the one big grid.

Assuming your calling code looks something like this:

```
int totalWidth = 200;

// draw big grid
drawGrid(g, 0, 0, totalWidth);

// draw small grids
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        drawGrid(g, totalWidth / 3 * i, totalWidth / 3 * j, totalWidth / 3);
    }
}
```

Here's what I would do:

```
private void drawGrid(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width) {
    // draw box around grid (not necessary)
    //g.drawRect(x, y, width, width);

    // draw vertical grid lines
    g.drawLine(width / 3 + x, y, width / 3 + x, y + width);
    g.drawLine(width / 3 * 2 + x, y, width / 3 * 2 + x, y + width);

    // draw horizontal grid lines
    g.drawLine(x, width / 3 + y, x + width, width / 3 + y);
    g.drawLine(x, width / 3 * 2 + y, x + width, width / 3 * 2 + y);
}
```

Note this doesn't put any padding around the small grids, so it looks like one huge grid. I imagine you'll want to add some padding to make it look right. You'd do that from the calling code where it loops to create the small grids.

Answer (score 0):

Um.  Besides the fact that it appears your asking us to do the work for you...

I would suggest not even using the Java Graphics to draw the shape of an x and to draw the shape of an o (it'll make your program all dirty, but you know.. whatever this is a tutorial).  Rather, I would a series of panels JTextAreas.  Give them a giant font, and make their 'isFocusable()' boolean to false.  Then, I would add mouse listeners to each of them, so whenever the mouse clicks the JTextArea, it runs a method.  I will write a method for you here, it's very simple.  It will take one parameter, a JTextArea.  This will be the area that was clicked, which can be easily be found out, because you'll be calling this method inside the mouseListener's mousePressed() method.  Bare in mind, this will require a mouseListener for all 9 of your JTextAreas.  This method also assumes you have created two booleans, one for the first player and one for the second.  If it is Player1's turn, this method will find out, then change the turn to Player2's and vise versa. ****NOTE**** make sure you set the value of Player1 to true when you create it, or at least before this method is called.

```
public void makingMove(JTextArea jta) {
    if (player1) {
        jta.setText("x");
        player1 = false;
        player2 = true;
    }
    if (player2) {
        jta.setText("o");
        player1 = true;
        player2 = false;
    }

}
```

Hmm will this work? NO! what if you click a JTextArea that already has a letter in it? it'll replace it! We can't have that! so, now we need to change up our makingMove method, so we know we don't break any rules:

```
public void makingMove(JTextArea jta) {
    if (jta.getText() == null) {
        if (player1) {
            jta.setText("x");
            player1 = false;
            player2 = true;
        }
        if (player2) {
            jta.setText("o");
            player1 = true;
            player2 = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't move there, someone already has!");
    }
}
```

Done right? WRONG!  Now we need to create a method that will check to see if anyone has won yet!
We will call this after our else statement in our makingMove() method. Like so:

```
.....
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't move there, someone already has!");
    }
checkWinnerX(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
checkWinnerY(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
}
```

The checkWinnerX method will have to take 9 parameters, same with our checkWinnerO method.  Each input object will be a JTextArea, so we can compare their input.  This method assumes, your JTextAreas are named 1-9, counting like it would be a phone's dialpad.  In addition, we have our checkWinnerX and checkWinnerO methods calling a method to clear everything, and reset the game, which you can assign to a button if you'd like, but I would definitely recommend having one.
*****NOTE******
I will not write the checkWinnerO method because it is the same as the checkWinnerX, but with all o's instead.  and I'm sure you get the idea. AND this is an EXTREMELY inefficient way of handling this, but oh well.

```
public static void checkWinnerX(JTextArea 1, JTextArea 2, etc.. up to 9) {
    if (1.equals("x") && 2.equals("x") && 3.equals("x")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue(null, "The winner is X!");
        clear();
    }
    if (4.equals("x") && 5.equals("x") && 6.equals("x")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue(null, "The winner is X!");
        clear();

    }
    if (7.equals("x") && 8.equals("x") && 9.equals("x")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue(null, "The winner is X!");
        clear();

    }
    if (1.equals("x") && 2.equals("x") && 3.equals("x")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue(null, "The winner is X!");
        clear();

    }
    if (1.equals("x") && 5.equals("x") && 9.equals("x")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue(null, "The winner is X!");
        clear();

    }
    if (7.equals("x") && 5.equals("x") && 3.equals("x")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue(null, "The winner is X!");
        clear();

    }
    if (1.equals("x") && 4.equals("x") && 7.equals("x")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue(null, "The winner is X!");
        clear();

    }
    if (2.equals("x") && 5.equals("x") && 8.equals("x")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue(null, "The winner is X!");
        clear();

    }
    if (3.equals("x") && 6.equals("x") && 9.equals("x")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue(null, "The winner is X!");
        clear();

    }
}

public static void clear() {
    1.setText(null);
    2.setText(null);
    3.setText(null);
    4.setText(null);
    5.setText(null);
    6.setText(null);
    7.setText(null);
    8.setText(null);
    9.setText(null);
}
```

Now if you've got your mouseListeners set up correctly, and you use GridBagConstraints to correctly format your playing board.  You pretty much have it done.
I could make this a thousand ways, using a thousand different methods and objects and blah, I chose this way because you specified you wanted an 'algorithm' for it.  Now, you should be able to refer to this VERY broken down tutorial of a not-so-great way of making this game, and write your own code for it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a .PNG for the X and the O pictures.

Comment: Also, this is 6 lines of code. While it may appear that I'm "making" you do the work for me, I already pointed out what this is for. I'm merely asking for help with the `drawLine` statements to make them universal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a 3 x 3 grid of tic tac toe boards.

Here's a quick Swing application that draws a 3 x 3 grid of tic tac toe boards.  9 tic tac toe boards on 9 panels.

[image: Tic Tac Toe board]

And here's the code.  The drawing code is in the DrawingPanel class.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TicTacToe implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private List<DrawingPanel> drawingPanels;

    public TicTacToe() {
        this.drawingPanels = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Ultimate Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
            mainPanel.add(drawingPanel);
            drawingPanels.add(drawingPanel);
        }


        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void exitProcedure() {
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TicTacToe());
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3774580797998095321L;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 170));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0F));
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            int sectionWidth = r.width / 3;
            int sectionHeight = r.height / 3;

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawLine(r.x, r.y + sectionHeight, 
                    r.x + r.width, r.y + sectionHeight);
            g2d.drawLine(r.x, r.y + sectionHeight + sectionHeight, 
                    r.x + r.width, r.y + sectionHeight + sectionHeight);
            g2d.drawLine(r.x + sectionWidth, r.y, r.x + sectionWidth, 
                    r.y + r.height);
            g2d.drawLine(r.x + sectionWidth + sectionWidth, r.y, 
                    r.x + sectionWidth + sectionWidth, r.y + r.height);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is all in one panel, which works, but there is a reason I want 9 panels. Initially I did have it in 1 panel, but then I've added a `mouseListener` to it so that I can enable/disable the ones that cannot be clicked at the time.

Comment: Where did you mention that you want 9 panels?  I missed it.

Comment: I've changed the answer to create 9 panels.